# iis 7.5 site not reachable through external ip adress from router

Tags: router, iis-7.5, port-forwarding

I'm hosting a test site under iis 7.5 on windows server 2008 r2. The firewall is deactivated and my router (fritz!box) has a rule to forward the port 3130 to my test server.

The test site is reachable under the local server ip on port 3130.
Trying to reach the test site via my router's internet ip adress on port 3130 brings the message that the page can not be displayed.

http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ says the port is closed.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Site bindings are set to "any ip" with port 3130. Although the firewall is deactivated, I've created a rule to allow the port 3130 to any program and ip. I've configured remote desktop port forwarding too. At this moment I'm connected via internet over remote desktop with the server.

Comment: This question isn't really answerable in its current form.  Can you provide us with the IP address to test as well?  Have you checked your IIS port bindings to make sure the site is running on port 3130 as opposed to the standard port 80?

Comment: Site bindings are set to "any ip" with port 3130.
I don't want to publish the ip address here, could I mail it to you?

Comment: Remote desktop is working via internet and port forwarding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed, after restarting my router I'd to add the port forwarding rules again and now it is working.